# import Python files in Azure function

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-functions, python-module

I did import a file in azure function in a structure like this

```
from folder1.folder.script import function
```

but it showed me error
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder1'

whene I tried outside the azure function it worked so any idea why it's can't be accessed within the function

Comment: Is `script` the file name? to import function from another folder/directory, this code works: `from application.app.folder.file import func_name`

Answer (score 2):

**Created a Folder `calcfunction` and added the `add_number` function**:

```
def  add_number(n1,n2):
sum = n1 + n2;
return  sum;
print("The sum of two number is",sum)
```

**Calling this method from Azure Function Python Class**:

```
import  logging
import  azure.functions  as  func

from calcfunction import  calc

def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

id = req.params.get('id')

if  not  id:
try:
req_body = req.get_json()
except  ValueError:
pass
else:
id = req_body.get('id')

if  id:
return  func.HttpResponse(f"This is the user entered userId {id} and calc function value {calc.add_number(12,24)}")

else:
return  func.HttpResponse(
"This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a ID in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
status_code=200
)
```

**My Azure Functions Project Folder Structure and the result**:

[image]