# Azure http trigger functions throwing an error over imported modules from other folder

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-http-trigger

We are building an http trigger using Azure functions.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

From the online platform, we were able to trigger it by adding a parameter and print it on the screen.

Once we try to import files from src folder which at the same level of `HttpTrigger1`,

```
import src.main
```

[image]

We have the following error:

> Error in load_function. Sys Path:
> ['C:\Users\AliMehdy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.10\WINDOWS\X64',

And it points out to `main.py` where we have already loaded a library called `load_toml`. Also over each import in main.py from src folder.

[image]

So it's throwing the same error over each module.

We did check the [documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-configuration#import-behavior) and specifically that part:

> When you're using absolute import syntax, the shared_code/ folder
> needs to contain an **init**.py file to mark it as a Python package.

Still, we didn't know what to do. Any idea how to import other modules into Azure http trigger function?

Comment: could you post a screenshot of the contents of `src` and `main.py`?

Answer (score 0):

In One of my previous [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71998078/import-python-files-in-azure-function), I have created a Python File in the **src** like folder which is at the same level of **HttpTrigger** Function Folder level in the Azure Functions Python Project.

```py
from calcfunction import  calc
```

This is the absolute path I have used in that Http Trigger Function:

[image]

Absolute paths are good to use for the above scenarios such as importing modules as a python package in other files.

Refer to this similar scenario on SO #[58318794](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58322407) provided by the user @*HassanAbbas*.